# Rails 4: one to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have one to many association between jobs and company, and I want  when creating a job i select the name of the company and enter the job info so when save the job and return to the company page i see the job title, but with this codes i get nothing

this is my company model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_many :jobs    
end
```

this is the job model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
end
```

this is the job form view

```
<div class="form-group">

        <%= f.label :company %><br />
        <%= f.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Choisir votre société"  %>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :job_title, "Intitulé du poste", class: "jobs-newtitles" %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :job_title, class: "form-control form-newjob"  %>
</div>
```

and this is my company show view

```
        <% if @company.jobs.blank? %>

          <h3> this company have no job</h3>

        <% else %>

          <div class = "job-description-profile-section" >
            <%= @company.jobs.job_title %>
          </div>

        <% end %>
```

Comment: Is your form working, ie does the input save to the database? Usually you would make loop of all the jobs instead of @company.jobs.job_title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your job is correctly saved in the database but you are getting error while accessing a job_title in show view of Company.

`@company.jobs` would return a array of jobs associated with the particular company.

Instead of `<%= @company.jobs.job_title %>` (which would definitely give an error)

in the Company show view, what you need is

```
<% @company.jobs.each do |job| %>
   <%= job.job_title %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

Even after updating the code, if you see `this company have no job` on the screen after saving a job. Then it means that `company_id` attribute is not getting stored for the particular job.

Make sure that you permit `company_id` to be saved, in your controller.

For ex.

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:job_title, :company_id)
end
```

Comment: yes you are right but even this solution return empty however thank you for your suggestion

Comment: What do you mean by empty? Do you see  'this company have no job' displayed on screen and no job_titles?

Comment: thank you verry much now it work now it was a 'strong parameters' problem